# How to make the function can process different type image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat

Cross post [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/188338/how-to-make-the-function-can-process-different-type-image/)

---

I have build two function with different name to drop the specfiy lines from difference `Mat` object, this is the code:

```
Mat drop_rows_int(Mat mat, vector<int> v) {
    Mat mat_new = Mat::zeros(mat.rows - v.size(), mat.cols, CV_32SC1);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), i) != v.end())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            int*pmat = mat.ptr<int>(i);
            int*pmat_new = mat_new.ptr<int>(j);
            for (int w = 0; w < mat.cols; w++) {
                pmat_new[w] = pmat[w];
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return mat_new;
}

Mat drop_rows_uchar(Mat mat, vector<int> v) {
    Mat mat_new = Mat::zeros(mat.rows - v.size(), mat.cols, CV_8UC1);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), i) != v.end())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            uchar*pmat = mat.ptr<uchar>(i);
            uchar*pmat_new = mat_new.ptr<uchar>(j);
            for (int w = 0; w < mat.cols; w++) {
                pmat_new[w] = pmat[w];
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return mat_new;
}
```

Then I can use it in my `main()` function like

```
int main()
{
    Mat mat_uchar = (Mat_<uchar>(5, 4) << 5, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 9, 9, 100, 3, 5, 8, 200, 33, 1, 4, 8, 88, 23, 6);
    Mat new_mat_uchar = drop_rows_uchar(mat_uchar, {2,4});

    Mat mat_int = (Mat_<int>(5, 4) << 5, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 9, 9, 100, 3, 5, 8, 200, 33, 1, 4, 8, 88, 23, 6);
    Mat new_mat_int = drop_rows_int(mat_int, { 2,4 });

        return 0;
}
```

Yes, I made it. but as I know, the `Mat` can have 7 kinds of depth, such as `CV_8U`, `CV_8S`, `CV_16U`, `CV_16S`, `CV_32S`, `CV_32F` and `CV_64F`, So I have to build 7 functions with different name to do such thing?? Can anyone tell me how to use **one function** to implement it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with `cv::Mat`. However, you can use `cv::Mat_` and do some templating:

```
template<typename T>
cv::Mat_<T> drop_rows_int(cv::Mat_ mat, vector<int> v) {
...
}
```

And here you extract pointers of type T.

Just a piece of advice, for efficiency purposes I suggest sending the vector `v` as a const reference, if possible.

---

Here is the full solution:

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
cv::Mat_<T> drop_rows(cv::Mat_<T> mat, const std::vector<int> &v) {
    cv::Mat_<T> mat_new = cv::Mat_<T>::zeros(mat.rows - v.size(), mat.cols);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        if (find(v.begin(), v.end(), i) != v.end())
            continue;
        else {
            for (int w = 0; w < mat.cols; w++) {
                mat_new(j, w) = mat(i, w);
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return mat_new;
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat_<uchar> mat = (cv::Mat_<uchar>(5, 4) << 5, 6, 0, 4, 0, 1, 9, 9, 100, 3, 5, 8, 200, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    auto result = drop_rows(mat, {2, 4});

    std::cout << mat << std::endl;;
    std::cout << result << std::endl;;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it works only for `Mat_`, not for `Mat`.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand it totally. This is my try as [you say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0RlK.png) Could you mind to show a totally solution? But I will get a error information when I run the code

Comment: I updated the answer. As a future rule of thumb, never take pictures to code. Always pastebin ;).